# GPG - old password works instead of new one

Tags: password, encryption, gnupg

Strange situation here: I changed my GPG password some time ago but when using script to encrypt/decrypt folder, I have to enter my **old password** to decrypt files.

- I changed password to my GPG key (gpg passwd )
- Seahorse will accept only new password
- When I encrypt file with `gpg -ea -r my@email.com file` (or with main-key-id), than I'm able to decrypt it with new password

The trouble is, that when I use the command `gpg --trust-model always --batch --yes -ea -r <pub-key-ID> <file.txt>` in the script, I cannot decrypt file with my new password. Only my old password works.

I'm completely baffled. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sometimes using `gpg`, sometimes `gpg2` (or a GUI application like Enigmail)?

Comment: Yes, I use enigmail as well while using "gpg" command in scripts. `gpg --version` returns  `gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.11, libgcrypt 1.6.5`. But this problem occures when using only `gpg` commands. Weird.

Comment: It seems that this problem is still unsolved. I tried to change password via `gpg --edit-key xxxxxx` as well as `gpg2 --edit-key xxxxxx`, but it won't fix it. In same cases, my old password is the only one that works.

Comment: Make sure you don't use GnuPG with multiple user accounts or have special keyrings stored on non-default locations (but then again, these would not be picked up normally).

Comment: I moved `.gnupg` folder to encrypted location and symlinked it back. Is there anything else I have to do? I noticed, that I cannot decrypt file in script but the same command in terminal works just fine. Some environmental problems?

Comment: Are you executing the script as root or using sudo (or some automated tasks)? The probably most common issue in such cases is executing GnuPG from another user account, which reads from another location (for example `root`'s user folder or web server system users, ...).

Comment: No, I run script manually as my own user via "bash /absolute/path/command.sh". If I run script content in the terminal shell, it can be decrypted with new password and the old password is rejected (which is right).

Comment: Then there _must_ be some difference in how GnuPG is called. Try putting a `set +x` on top of the script (which outputs every command executed with variables substituted) and compare command executed by the script with what you run manually. Also consider environment variables set by the script.

Comment: The command to decrypt is in both cases `gpg file.txt.asc`, simple as that. And it's encrypted just the same - it can be decrypted by two different passwords though. How it is possible that my computer remembers the old one once the key has been re-passphrased?

Comment: Ha! I accidentally noticed this alias `alias gpg="gpg2"` that explains it all... #facepalm Thank you for your help, @JensErat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out afterall:

- There were different secret keys in gpg and gpg2
- I had an alias `alias gpg="gpg2"`
- Script was working with "gpg" while shell worked with gpg2 (even when I thought the otherwise)